# How to replace ttk.Treeview parent node arrow with an image?

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, treeviewitem

**Question:** How does one create in tkinter.ttk.Treeview a node where the toggling arrow of the node is replaced by a defined image? That is, how do I get from my second picture to the first picture as shown below.

**Problem:** The New Mexico Tech Guide showed that [tkinter.ttk.Treeview](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html) can create a folder directory as shown below:

[image: To Achieve]

Using the tkinter.ttk.Treeview .insert() method with an "image" keyword, I am only able to achieve the below. An image does appear on the left of the node text, but the image does not replace the arrow toggling the opening and closing of the node to reveal its descendants. I had assumed the image defined by the "image" keyword would replace the toggling arrows. But this did not happen.

[image: Achieved so far]

**Test Code:**

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, path):

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Directory', anchor='w')

        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        i = './icon/Home-icon_16.gif'
        self.root_pic = tk.PhotoImage(file=i)
        root_node = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text='  Work Folder', open=True, image=self.root_pic)
        l1_node = self.tree.insert(root_node, 'end', text='level 1', open=True)
        l2_node = self.tree.insert(l1_node, 'end', text='level 2', open=True)
        l3_node = self.tree.insert(l2_node, 'end', text='level 3', open=True)
        l2a_node = self.tree.insert(l1_node, 'end', text='level 2a', open=True)
        l3a_node = self.tree.insert(l2a_node, 'end', text='level 3a', open=True)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
path_to_my_project = os.getcwd()
app = App(root, path=path_to_my_project)
app.mainloop()
```

**Home-icon_16.gif:**[image: Home-icon_16.gif]

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need this anymore, but for anyone else, this is how I managed it.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()

window.eval("""
# Load the path of the images
variable directory

# Use if images are in the same directory as the program:
set directory [file dirname [info script]]

# Use if images are in a different directory to the program:
# set directory [file join [file dirname [info script]] <Directory Name>]

variable images
# Load the images
# Image names are the filenames of the image files without the extension (e.g., image.png --> image)
foreach file [glob -directory $directory *.png] {
    set img [file tail [file rootname $file]]
    set images($img) [image create photo -file $file -format png]
}

# Create a new indicator element
ttk::style element create Custom.Treeitem.indicator \
    image [list $images(<Collapsed Node Image Name>) user2 $images(<Empty Image>) user1 $images(<Expanded Node Image Name>)] \
    -width <Image Size> -sticky n
""")

style = ttk.Style()

# Add the newly created indicator element to the layout of 'Custom.Treeview.Item'
style.layout('Custom.Treeview.Item', [('Treeitem.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Custom.Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}), ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}), ('Treeitem.text', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})])

## Create a new treeview with the style 'Custom.Treeview'
tree = ttk.Treeview(window, style='Custom.Treeview')
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSWE')

window.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, this approach means all the node arrows have the same image, but it may still be helpful.